# I get a bunch of errors when running npm install

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm-install, git-bash

I'm trying to get into full stack web dev, so I'm fairly new. Just recently I was installing node.js onto my laptop, I'm following this course and I had to clone a github repo onto my bash terminal and run the `npm install` but it came up with a whole list of errors.

I tried running things on a Virtual Environment, reinstalling node.js among some possible solutions online but with no luck. I'm hoping someone would help me out here, I'd appreciate that. Below is the log for my errors:

Thanks a lot

````
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Kevin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\code\\javascript\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.5.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\code\\javascript\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Kevin\OneDrive\Desktop\code\javascript\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1```
````

Comment: What environment is this? I don't know about Linux but when you install the Windows version of Node you get the option to install dependencies like Python.

Comment: Yes, I did that. During the installation I grabbed the Chocolatey package manager too. I ran the ```npm install express``` command and that somehow did it tho

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this Node version requires Python 2x and you have Python 3x added to the path. Try downloading Python 2x and adding it to the path.

Comment: I actually tried that yesterday, but I had a problem where despite me trying to manually go down to Python 2. it would stay on 3. -I ran the ```pyenv virtualenv 2.7.18 env``` command to no avail. I tried running the `npm install express` command just now and I think it works, I'm getting no errors